How to copy keys from one Redis database to another?
I have a Redis instance with multiple databases. I want to perform a full copy of the DB1 to DB2 on the same instance. What is the most optimal way to do this? I tried MIGRATE, but it seems it's not possible to use it since I'm copying within one instance

Does this answer your question? Copy all keys from one db to another in redis
